# How do I export an object from here to another file?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, export

I need to export and object after parsing html. So that I can import this file in another and the Obj would be the same as inside the function.

```
const https = require('https');

const url = "https://..."

https.get(url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    const Obj = {}

    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
        Obj.data = 'data' // how do I get the Obj with key and value from here and export it to another file?
 
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});

module.exports = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw HTTP request inside async function (that returns `Promise`) and export this function. And just call this function in another file where you import (with `await` or `.then`).